# Remove Play/Pause on embedded youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, embed

I have embedded a youtube video on my site, and want to remove all play/pause functionality form it. I have already made it so that the controls are not visible; however, the video still pauses when the user clicks on the video.

I'm using a youtube "player" and div to embed it:

```
<div id="player" style="position: absolute; width:100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0">   </div>

<script>
var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      videoId: 'Ir8-0xOptFA',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'showinfo' : 0, 'wmode' : 'transparent', 'modestbranding': 1},
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      },
      version: 3
    });
  }
 </script>
```

The idea is that this video will serve as the 'background' for the main page of the site. Any insights would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about overlaying a transparent DIV?

[Your question may have already been answered here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429884/youtube-iframe-disable-pause-video)

Answer (score -1):

Look into [**THIS**](http://activeden.net/forums/thread/removing-play-button-over-youtube-player/38692) link

And [**THIS**](http://activeden.net/forums/thread/youtube-chromeless-api-question/37602#353888) link.

You may have to load the preview image in place of the button. Not sure if that will help