# Youtube iframe api. How disable touchmove focus?

Tags: javascript, youtube, touchmove

Youtube iframe api. How disable touch  focus? I need to have the video play immediately and not get a mouse event(click descop and touchmove in mobile).

Answer (score 0):

You can use css (into your iframe parent tag)

```
{pointer-events: none;}
```

if you want permanently remove touch move, you can use these class.
if conditionally, you need to work on
detect the video is start point and end point,  start point add this class into your parent iframe , when video ended remove the class.

refer [would be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429884/youtube-iframe-disable-pause-video)

Comment: Sorry, me need disable iframe only event "touch move".