# Javascript code for disabling mouse click for youtube videos

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, qualtrics

I am designing an experiment making people watch a youtube video and I would like to keep them from controlling or stopping the video.

Also, it seems I can't use css since I am using a basic experiment software called Qualtrics.

I tried iframe "controls" and "disablekb" options but they didn't work. Also, "hideControls" doesn't work.

In the html (Qualtrics), I added
[this simple html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO643.png) and then I typed most codes in javascript:

```
var videoId = 'vpTHi7O66pI';
var hideControls = true;

// This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
if (hideControls) {
    hideControls = 0;
} else {
    hideControls = 1;
}

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: videoId,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        },
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1,
            modestbranding: 1,
            rel: 0,
            disablekb: 1,
            enablejsapi: 1,
            showinfo: 0,
            controls: 0
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.contextmenu(function() {
     return false;
    });
    player.setPlaybackRate(1.25);
    player.loadVideoById({'videoId': videoId,
           'suggestedQuality': 'large'});
    event.target.playVideo();
}
window.setTimeout(function() {
    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(); 
}, 1000);
```

I expect mouse clicking doesn't lead to pausing the video but it pauses.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet so we can test; it would be easier to help...

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the `pointer-events: none;` CSS property in an inline style element on the player's encapsulating element.

For example, in your HTML you can use:

```
<style>#player {pointer-events: none}</style>
```

Comment: thank you i used your solution and worked as charm.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a transparent overlay over the player itself, like a div, then stop the click event when it happens in there (could be with CSS, setting it's pointer events as `pointer-events: none`).

Answer (score 1):

I have the most awesome answer if you're flexible about a JS solution - CSS can actually do this:

```
#container_id {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Now the mouse won't interact with the controls at all (hover or click)

Edit: If JS is a requirement:

```
document.getElementById('container_id').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

Final edit: Sorry, did not read as carefully as I should :(

Looks like you are loading the player markup into var player - you should be able to add the prevent default onclick directly to that var as such:

```
player.onclick = function(event){ event.preventDefault() }
```

Good luck!

In response:

Each approach mentioned above was a different option, the middle one supposes access to the DOM, but I'm starting to sense you can't directly manipulate it based on what you've said - so I recommend the last implementation, I would try either of these:

Under:

```
player.setPlaybackRate(1.25);
player.loadVideoById({'videoId': videoId,
       'suggestedQuality': 'large'});
```

Add:

```
player.onclick = function(event){ event.preventDefault() }
```

Or:

```
event.target.onclick = function(event){ event.preventDefault() }
```

I like the first one better for readability, but they might both work, without more info about the [ YT.Player ] (I assume a library you're using) I can't be sure the object bound to [ var player ] will allow it's onclick to be modified (some libraries include measures to prevent things like that) - so I include option 2 as a fallback - let me know if that doesn't work because there are other event binding options...

The CSS approach at the top is your last ditch effort, it would solve the problem on it's own, no need for any of the JS. It would be added between the

```
<style> and </style>
```

tags in the documents head, like so:

```
<head>
[ STUFF ]
<style>
  #[THE_ID_OF_YOUR_CONTAINER] {
     pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
```

or included in a stylesheet - likely named [something].css on your server as just:

```
iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure where I should put the code. It didn't work when I simply added your last code, or when I put it below the line "function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {" in my code. Should I add all three codes that you suggested?

Comment: Answer updated to show implementation options - there are other approaches if that doesn't work, but at least one of them should...

Comment: I tried your codes and they didn't work. I think I am observing mouse hovering itself interacts with youtube video controls although I blocked the control function but youtube still shows the title even before mouse clicking. I am not sure if this will help though.

Comment: WOW - The YouTube player is AGGRESSIVE 8O - so, the options left are to disable the event listeners that they have bound, by name - which would require either digging through the player's source code, or the documentation, and hoping they were attached with names (if they aren't - they can't be unbound), I posit the CSS rout is much more tenable, I'm still not entirely sure if JS is a requirement or not, but it's not very realistic here...

Comment: I added one last edit - the CSS for the iframe (very bottom), I think this is your best option

Comment: you know, if you can't edit the stylesheet directly, you could try modifying the CSS of the iframe with JS, is there a way to add CSS, or does it absolutely have to be there in the JS?

Comment: I really appreciate your comment. I don't know why, (probably it is me) but I failed to use your way. I also couldn't find CSS editor in Qualtrics too. Instead, I followed Corey Deschambault's method of overlapping another layer above the video: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429884/youtube-iframe-disable-pause-video

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but recently ran into the same problem. I am trying to show a video as part of an experiment on memory. The plan is to record button presses, so it would be tricky with the timing if viewers can pause the video.

The video is hosted here: https://muse.ai/docs#embed-player,
which should in theory allow me to implement the solutions above. However, the movie is still pausable on a mouse-click.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
    <style>
      #container-name{
         pointer-events: none;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://muse.ai/static/js/embed-player.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="width: 840px; background-color: grey;">

<div id="container-name" ></div>

<script src="https://muse.ai/static/js/embed-player.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const player = MusePlayer({
    container: '#container-name',
    video: 'zT4Vmcc',
    width: 800,
    autoplay: true,
    style: 'no-controls',
  });
  event.target.onclick = function(event){ event.preventDefault() }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I tried to implement two of the solutions above. Any input would be apprechiated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
    <style>
    </style>
    <script src="https://muse.ai/static/js/embed-player.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="width: 840px; background-color: grey;">

<div id="container-name" ></div>

<script src="https://muse.ai/static/js/embed-player.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const player = MusePlayer({
    container: '#container-name',
    video: 'zT4Vmcc',
    style: 'no-controls',
    logo: false,
    search: false,
    title: false,
    autoplay: true,
    shortcuts: false,
    css: '*{pointer-events:none!important;}',
  });
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Which is also what juandxce suggested, thanks!